# mx:RadioButtonGroup not working under mx:GridItem in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I had tried to use the radioButtonGroup under the GridItem in flex4. but it is not working.

The code:

```
<mx:GridItem >  

<mx:RadioButtonGroup id="scheduleSelectionGroup" click="showScheduleSetting(event);"/>

<mx:HBox>       

<eov:HPRadioButton value="{CreateVO.DAILY}" 
                                           label="Daily"
                                               id="dailyRB" 
                                           selected="true"  
                                           groupName="{SelectionGroup}" 
                                           change="showSetting(event)"/>

<eov:HPRadioButton id="weeklyRB"
                                               value="{CreateVO.WEEKLY}"
                                               label="Weekly"   
                                           groupName="{SelectionGroup}" 
                                           change="showSetting(event)"/>

<eov:HPRadioButton  label="Monthly"
                                               value="{CreateVO.MONTHLY}"   
                                           id="monthlyRB"   
                                           groupName="{SelectionGroup}"
                                               change="showSetting(event)"/>

</mx:HBox>

</mx:GridItem>
```

and the

```
public function showSetting(event:Event):void{

    if(SelectionGroup.selectedValue == CreateVO.DAILY){

    dailyRB.visible=true;

    }
}
```

It is not working. If any one knows how to assign values to radioButtonGroup to call the `showSetting()` function.

Comment: Please remember: StackOverflow allows you to format your question so potential answerers can read it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadioButtonGroup is a non-graphic component. It is simply an object using which you can group many radiobuttons.

So, it will go in the `Declarations` tag

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="scheduleSelectionGroup" click="showScheduleSetting(event);"/>
</fx:Declarations>
```

And, you have to put radioButtons which belong to that group like this:

```
<mx:RadioButton groupName="scheduleSelectionGroup" value="value0" label="RadioButton0" />
```

That is: you have to put the value of the `id` attribute for the group in the `groupName` attribute of the radiobutton

So your radioButtons would be like:

```
<eov:HPRadioButton value="{CreateVO.DAILY}" 
                                           label="Daily"
                                           id="dailyRB" 
                                           selected="true"  
                                           groupName="scheduleSelectionGroup" 
                                           change="showSetting(event)"/>

<eov:HPRadioButton id="weeklyRB"
                                               value="{CreateVO.WEEKLY}"
                                               label="Weekly"   
                                           groupName="scheduleSelectionGroup" 
                                           change="showSetting(event)"/>

<eov:HPRadioButton  label="Monthly"
                                               value="{CreateVO.MONTHLY}"   
                                           id="monthlyRB"   
                                           groupName="scheduleSelectionGroup"
                                               change="showSetting(event)"/>
```